# fontspec optical sizes

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, harfbuzz

I am trying to set up variable fonts on `LuaLaTeX` via the `fontspec` package. I am trying to get the font size and the optical size (`opsz`) to have nearly the same value. (I am aware that the `opsz` variable axis must be between `6` and `144` with a step of `0.1` so the numbers won't be perfectly synced. See: https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/glossary/optical_size_axis)

The `fontspec` documentation makes it seem like you have to manually set the optical size for each font size and that you have to add an additional font size-optical size pair each time you add a new font. Obviously, this would be exhausting and take a long time. I would prefer that the optical size (almost always) equals the font size automatically. (`{Size=X,RawFeature={axis={opsz=X}}}` for every possible value for X.)

In the following MWE, I manually set the optical size for each font size defined by the `article` document class. (And, for some reason, the line spacing for the paragraphs with `\LARGE`,`\huge`, and `\Huge` is messed up.)

EDIT: I have added the code for Bold, Italics, and Bold Italics to help the reader understand how tedious it would be to manually set the optical size for each font size. I haven't even set up the commands for different weights: ExtraLight, Light, Medium, SemiBold, ExtraBold, and Black.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in]{geometry}
\raggedright\raggedbottom
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=7pt
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}%Available for free on Google Fonts.
\setmainfont{SourceSerif4-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}[%Available for free on Google Fonts.
    ,Kerning=On,Numbers={Lining,Tabular}
    %Regular
    ,SizeFeatures={
        {Size=7,RawFeature={axis={opsz=7}}}%\scriptsize
        ,{Size=8,RawFeature={axis={opsz=8}}}%\footnotesize
        ,{Size=9,RawFeature={axis={opsz=9}}}%\small
        ,{Size=10,RawFeature={axis={opsz=10}}}%\normalsize
        ,{Size=12,RawFeature={axis={opsz=12}}}%\large
        ,{Size=14.4,RawFeature={axis={opsz=14.4}}}%\Large
        ,{Size=17.28,RawFeature={axis={opsz=17.3}}}%\LARGE
        ,{Size=20.74,RawFeature={axis={opsz=20.7}}}%\huge
        ,{Size=24.88,RawFeature={axis={opsz=24.9}}}%\Huge
    }
    %Bold
    ,BoldFont={SourceSerif4-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}
    ,BoldFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={
            {Size=7,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=7}}}%\scriptsize
            ,{Size=8,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=8}}}%\footnotesize
            ,{Size=9,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=9}}}%\small
            ,{Size=10,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=10}}}%\normalsize
            ,{Size=12,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=12}}}%\large
            ,{Size=14.4,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=14.4}}}%\Large
            ,{Size=17.28,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=17.3}}}%\LARGE
            ,{Size=20.74,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=20.7}}}%\huge
            ,{Size=24.88,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=24.9}}}%\Huge
        }
    }
    %Italics
    ,ItalicFont={SourceSerif4-Italic-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}
    ,ItalicFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={
            {Size=7,RawFeature={axis={opsz=7}}}%\scriptsize
            ,{Size=8,RawFeature={axis={opsz=8}}}%\footnotesize
            ,{Size=9,RawFeature={axis={opsz=9}}}%\small
            ,{Size=10,RawFeature={axis={opsz=10}}}%\normalsize
            ,{Size=12,RawFeature={axis={opsz=12}}}%\large
            ,{Size=14.4,RawFeature={axis={opsz=14.4}}}%\Large
            ,{Size=17.28,RawFeature={axis={opsz=17.3}}}%\LARGE
            ,{Size=20.74,RawFeature={axis={opsz=20.7}}}%\huge
            ,{Size=24.88,RawFeature={axis={opsz=24.9}}}%\Huge
        }
    }
    %Bold Italics
    ,BoldItalicFont={SourceSerif4-Italic-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}
    ,BoldItalicFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={
            {Size=7,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=7}}}%\scriptsize
            ,{Size=8,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=8}}}%\footnotesize
            ,{Size=9,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=9}}}%\small
            ,{Size=10,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=10}}}%\normalsize
            ,{Size=12,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=12}}}%\large
            ,{Size=14.4,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=14.4}}}%\Large
            ,{Size=17.28,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=17.3}}}%\LARGE
            ,{Size=20.74,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=20.7}}}%\huge
            ,{Size=24.88,RawFeature={axis={wght=700,opsz=24.9}}}%\Huge
        }
    }
]
\begin{document}
\texttt{REGULAR}
\par
{\scriptsize\texttt{scriptsize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\footnotesize\texttt{footnotesize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\small\texttt{small}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\normalsize\texttt{normalsize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\large\texttt{large}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\Large\texttt{Large}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\LARGE\texttt{LARGE}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\huge\texttt{huge}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\Huge\texttt{Huge}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
\texttt{BOLD}{\bfseries
\par
{\scriptsize\texttt{scriptsize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\footnotesize\texttt{footnotesize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\small\texttt{small}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\normalsize\texttt{normalsize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\large\texttt{large}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\Large\texttt{Large}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\LARGE\texttt{LARGE}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\huge\texttt{huge}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\Huge\texttt{Huge}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
}
\par
\texttt{ITALICS}{\itshape
\par
{\scriptsize\texttt{scriptsize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\footnotesize\texttt{footnotesize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\small\texttt{small}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\normalsize\texttt{normalsize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\large\texttt{large}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\Large\texttt{Large}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\LARGE\texttt{LARGE}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\huge\texttt{huge}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\Huge\texttt{Huge}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
}
\par
\texttt{BOLD ITALICS}{\itshape\bfseries
\par
{\scriptsize\texttt{scriptsize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\footnotesize\texttt{footnotesize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\small\texttt{small}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\normalsize\texttt{normalsize}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\large\texttt{large}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\Large\texttt{Large}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\LARGE\texttt{LARGE}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\huge\texttt{huge}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
\par
{\Huge\texttt{Huge}\hspace{0.5em}\blindtext}
}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE 2023-01-02: I have been testing the `HarfBuzz` method to auto-size the `opsz` axis as suggested by Marcel Kruger. I find that it has functionality other than auto-sizing the `opsz` axis. Two main issues:

(1) If I change the font to `Source Sans 3`, another variable font, (with nearly the same code as provided by Marcel Kruger) and test using/not using `HarfBuzz`, I find that the document versions with and without `HarfBuzz` look significantly different from each other. The document versions should look identical because `Source Sans 3` lacks an `opsz` axis. Thus, `Renderer=HarfBuzz` has additional functionality other than modifying the `opsz` axis. The added functionality may or may not be typographically optimal. You can see this for your yourself in the second MWE below.

(2) Using `Renderer=HarfBuzz` with `Source Serif 4` with the `\textls` letterspacing command from package `microtype` sometimes produces incorrect letterspacing. I haven't found a pattern of error, but I have replicated some of the error in my second MWE. I have found that I can fix this error by either using `Source Sans 3` instead or by setting `Kerning=Off` locally. In fixing this letterspacing error, I would prefer that the `\textls` command automatically locally disables kerning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}%clears default header footers
\fancyhead[C]{%
    %\addfontfeatures{Kerning=Off}%In my testing, this fixes the bugged letterspacing.
    \textls[100]{LETTERSPACING IS BUGGED}%
}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
    %\addfontfeatures{Kerning=Off}%In my testing, this fixes the bugged letterspacing.
    ~\textls[100]{BUGGED}%
    ~(%
    \textls[100]{LETTER}%
    ~\textls[100]{SPACING}%
    )%
}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}
\setromanfont{SourceSerif4-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}[%Available for free on Google Fonts.
    ,Kerning=On,Numbers={Lining,Tabular},Renderer=HarfBuzz
    %Bold
    ,BoldFont={SourceSerif4-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}
    ,BoldFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=700}}}
    %Italics
    ,ItalicFont={SourceSerif4-Italic-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}
    %Bold Italics
    ,BoldItalicFont={SourceSerif4-Italic-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}
    ,BoldItalicFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=700}}}
]
\setsansfont{SourceSans3-VariableFont_wght.ttf}[%Available for free on Google Fonts.
    Kerning=On
    %,Renderer=HarfBuzz%In my testing Renderer=HarfBuzz will change the text display even though Source Sans 3 lacks an opsz axis.
    %Regular
    ,RawFeature={axis={wght=400}}
    %Bold
    ,BoldFont={SourceSans3-VariableFont_wght.ttf}
    ,BoldFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=700}}}
    %Italics
    ,ItalicFont={SourceSans3-Italic-VariableFont_wght.ttf}
    ,ItalicFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=400}}}
    %Bold Italics
    ,BoldItalicFont={SourceSans3-Italic-VariableFont_wght.ttf}
    ,BoldItalicFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=700}}}
]
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{%use this to switch between serif and sans fonts
    \rmdefault%
    %\sfdefault%
}
\begin{document}
{%
    %\addfontfeatures{Kerning=Off}%In my testing, this fixes the bugged letterspacing. Note that I have disabled kerning locally to not mess up the rest of the document.
    \textls[100]{LETTER SPACING IS BUGGED}%
}%
\par
\blinddocument
\small\blinddocument
\tiny\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I used the `showhyphenation` package with `Renderer=HarfBuzz` enabled and found that the latter messes up hyphenation in significant ways. I tested this with other documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can request the HarfBuzz based renderer and don't specify any `opsz` feature. The HarfBuzz mode automatically determines the `opsz` from the font size if no explicit value is given:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}
\setmainfont{SourceSerif4-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}[%Available for free on Google Fonts.
    ,Kerning=On,Numbers={Lining,Tabular},Renderer=HarfBuzz
    %Bold
    ,BoldFont={SourceSerif4-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}
    ,BoldFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=700}}}
    %Italics
    ,ItalicFont={SourceSerif4-Italic-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}
    %Bold Italics
    ,BoldItalicFont={SourceSerif4-Italic-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf}
    ,BoldItalicFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=700}}}
]
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\small\blinddocument
\tiny\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The `Renderer=HarfBuzz` seems to get the correct optical sizing, but it seems to do other things as well. I have updated my original post to reflect my recent testing.